# click package tokens in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, token, python-click

I am working on a command line interface by using the *click* package in Python. I got struck at getting **token** as an argument in sub-command. For more details I am attaching an image on how i want the function like in this

[image]

As specified in the image I got stuck at that point, so please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

there you dont need any token interface it just a string name

```
@click.argument('tokens',nargs=-1)
```

when we use this way we get the output as you mentioned above.